# Prevent join with temp table doing full table scan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find all related records in a large table and update them based on a smaller recordset, but as soon as I do that, all performance goes out the window and it starts doing full table scans of a massive table.

Below is an example of what the table would look like after importing file3 (there's an index on the VoidID column and FileName as well)

The table is showing that ID #1 is related to ID#2 and vice versa, same for ID #4 and #5. ID #3 is a sale with no void.

After Importing File3, I want to look for all records where there is a sale and void in the same file, but only for the file that was just imported. So I'm using a temp table #Results where I only insert the ID's from File3, but when I add that temp table into the query, it does a full scan of the table and takes forever to run:

```
DECLARE @Import Table(ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, TransType varchar(10), VoidID int, FileName varchar(25))
INSERT INTO @Import
VALUES(1,'Sale',2,'File1'),(2,'Void',1,'File1'),(3,'Sale',NULL,'File2'),(4,'Sale',5,'File3'),(5,'Void',4,'File3')
SELECT * FROM @Import

CREATE table #Results(ID integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO #Results(ID)
SELECT ID FROM @Import WHERE FileName = 'File3'

select * from #Results

SELECT P1.ID
FROM @Import P1 INNER JOIN #Results R ON P1.ID = R.ID INNER JOIN @Import P2 ON P1.ID = P2.VoidID
WHERE P1.FileName = P2.FileName

DROP TABLE #Results
```

This works, but the full table scan is still running right now (over an hour) so that's really not acceptable.  The estimated execution plan shows no missing indexes.

How can I improve this query?

** EDIT Actual Query, Key, and Index**

```
UPDATE P1
SET Notes = 'Matching Sale, Void in same file.'
FROM 
PriceImport P1 INNER JOIN 
#ResultSet R ON P1.ID = R.ID INNER JOIN 
PriceImport P2 ON P1.ID = P2.VoidID
WHERE P1.FileName = P2.FileName 


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PriceImport] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_PriceImportID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_PriceImport_Transaction_Matching] ON [dbo].[PriceImport]
(
    [TransType] ASC,
    [VoidID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([ID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Look at the Execution plan and try and find out what is causing the table scan.  Are you missing an index on the table or the temp table?

Comment: It might be beneficial as well to look at the `EXCEPTS` syntax. In some cases, it could be faster.

Comment: do you really need the `WHERE P1.FileName = P2.FileName`

Comment: @db_brad, The execution plan shows no missing index.  If I take out the temp table and just do a full join, it does an index scan, as soon as I add the temp table it does a full table scan.  I also added a CREATE INDEX on the temp table after creation and still does a full scan.

Comment: @JamieD77, Yes, that's the important part, I need matching sales/voids within the same file.

Comment: Can you include the real query you are using?  Above seems to just be a close example.

Comment: @db_brad, added the code to an edit, it's pretty basic.  The problem is that the PriceImport table is >100million rows and the full table scans are brutal.

Comment: You haven't any proper indexes for non-full-table scans.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the need for the #temp
I get what you are trying to do but that should not be necessary
Please try this on your real table

```
select p2.id, P1.ID
  from table p1 
  join table p2
    on P1.ID = P2.VoidID
   and p1.filename = 'File3'
   and p2.filename = 'File3'
```

if those columns are indexed this should be smoking fast

if they are always in pairs you could do

```
and p2.id < P1.ID
```

this should be easy

**you have VoidID as the second - no kidding you have an index scan**
either make it the first or have a separate index for VoidID
**you have no index on filename - no kidding you are getting a table scan**

please post the query plan to this

```
UPDATE P1
SET Notes = 'Matching Sale, Void in same file.'
FROM PriceImport P1 
JOIN #ResultSet R 
       ON P1.ID = R.ID 
JOIN PriceImport P2 
       ON P1.ID       = P2.VoidID
      AND P1.FileName = P2.FileName 
      AND isnull(Notes, "") <> 'Matching Sale, Void in same file.'
```

if #ResultSet if the filename then this should be better

```
UPDATE P1
SET Notes = 'Matching Sale, Void in same file.'
FROM PriceImport P1 
JOIN #ResultSet R1 
       ON P1.ID = R1.ID 
JOIN PriceImport P2 
       ON P1.ID = P2.VoidID
      AND isNull(Notes, "") <> 'Matching Sale, Void in same file.'   -- locks are expensive
JOIN #ResultSet R2 
       ON P2.ID = R2.ID
```

have you considered loading everything #ResultSet doing this in #ResultSet?